# are there any alternatives for GetElementById?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Okay, I am new to JavaScript, so I really need help with this. I have a script, which looks like this:

```
  var p = new Ping();

  p.ping("http://bf3.in", function(data) {
    document.getElementById("ping").innerHTML = data;
  });

 ............. some code goes here ........

<td id = 'ping'>line 1</td>
<td id = 'ping'>line 2</td>
```

My problem is that there are multiple tags that want to use this function on, but I can only use id="ping" on one tag, so I need an alternative for getElementById, one that would allow me to use multiple tags.

----------------UPDATE-----------------------

this is my full code http://bf3.in/ping.txt
actually iam hosting some game servers so need to ping serevr ip.
here is where client login http://bf3.in/launcher/login.php
user name : juno
password : juno
thanks :)

Comment: Yes, use classes and  `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: There are alternatives to `getElementById()`, yes; but don't try and work around your broken and invalid HTML: fix the HTML. An `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `document.querySelectorAll` function to query any CSS selector, or you can use `document.getElementsByClassName` to query based on class. There's no way to query based on multiple ids, because elements can't have multiple IDs.

Be careful with either one that you convert its result to an array rather than an array-like object with `Array.from`, so that you can use extension methods like `filter` and `map`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
or you could use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Note, all of these will return a node list. So if you replace `getElementById` with any of these will just not work. You have to do something like this

```
p.ping("http://bf3.in", function(data) {
   document.querySelectorAll(".ping").forEach(function(element){
      element.innerHTML = data;
})
});
<td class='ping'>line 1</td>
<td class='ping'>line 2</td>
```

Assuming that you are trying to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 1):

An ID should only be used to refer to a single unique element. If you want to group elements together then use `class` - then you could do `document.getElementsByClassName('ping');` which will return an array of elements.

So:

```
<table>
     <td class = 'ping'>line 1</td>
     <td class = 'ping'>line 2</td>
</table>
```

then
`document.getElementsByClassName('ping');` will return an array containing both `td` elements. Which can be accessed using regular array indices.

But unless your table is going to display tabular data - you'd be better off using something like `div` instead of a table. It's not the 90's anymore.

Comment: It's `document.getElementsByClassName` and returns an *array-like* object, actually.

Comment: yeah i tried but not working   is this how to use ? <td class='ping'></td>

Comment: You html is invalid in your example - you need to wrap your `td` in a table tag. Then it will work. Or just change `td` for something like `div`

Comment: @SkRafeeq: Perhaps you can update the question to include what you've changed and what isn't working?  "I tried but it didn't work" isn't an answerable question.

Comment: @SkRafeeq: "Here's all my code, debug it for me" isn't a particularly useful update to the question.  The *specific question* regarding selecting HTML elements with JavaScript has been answered.  In what way is that *specific thing* not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the reason that an id must be unique within the document, use classes instead.

---

Lets suppose you have the following markup:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Ping</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

What you want to do is get all the elements with class `.ping`.

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which expects a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas. This will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is basically just a collection of nodes which you can iterate.

```js
(function() {

  let pings = document.querySelectorAll('.ping');

  function fetchPing(i) {
    return `ping ${i} data`; //..fetch ping data.
  }

  pings.forEach((p, i) => {
    p.textContent = fetchPing(i);
  });

})();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Ping</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
    <td class="ping">{{ ping }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Notes:

- If the data you are fetching is just plain text, please use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` for performance and security reasons.